# c# - How to reply for comment in LinkedIn?

Tags: c#, integration, linkedin-api

I'm trying to integrate LinkedIn in our application. I just want to know how to reply for comment in LinkedIn.

I've written this code.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string data = "<comments><comment><text>Check out the Reply!</text></comment></comments>";


            byte[] databytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            var request = new RestRequest { Path = "comments" };
            var credentials = new Hammock.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthCredentials
            {
                Type = OAuthType.AccessToken,
                SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
                ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
                ConsumerKey = "kmkzt9cqml1s",
                ConsumerSecret = "hNiwIrZWGSMykoD2",
                Token = "b3cbdca7-37a7-474f-a9a6-e21bb89917fe",
                TokenSecret = "990f1b78-79de-4490-b4e3-893b4e020e45",
            };
            var client = new RestClient()
            {
                Authority = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/g-457832-S-454334",
                Credentials = credentials,
                Method = WebMethod.Post,
            };

            client.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            client.AddPostContent(databytes);

            RestResponse response = client.Request(request);
            string content = response.Content;

        }
```

I'm getting an error in content in the below format

```
   <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>
   <error>  
     <status>400</status>
     <timestamp>1374494502579</timestamp>
     <request-id>QM4MYPEKJJ</request-id>  
   <error-code>0</error-code>
 <message>Couldn't parse message document: error: Unexpected end of file after null</message>\n</error>\n"
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.